# What do I need to know to buy an SSD drive for a 2008 MacBook 5,1?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I'd like to buy an SSD drive for my [MacBook aluminium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook#Unibody_aluminum_model) (MacBook5,1 from 2008). What do I need to know to buy one which will work fine with it?

I.e. years ago any IDE drive would fit any IDE slot, but I've never worked with SATA drives so I don't know if they are "just compatible" or there are some quirks, similar to what happens with RAM where you have to check the clock rate.

Comment: There is no such thing as "MacBook aluminium." The "unibody" MBPs range drastically and without knowing what exact model you have, no one can answer your question. Secondly, this is off topic. Please read the FAQ: questions about buying hardware aren't welcome here. Lastly, a google search for SSD and your exactly model of Mac will most likely answer your question.

Comment: @cksum I've linked it, there only one single model of MacBook unibody made of aluminium.

Comment: The question still violates the guidelines of this group I'm afraid. We have rules for a reason. It's also poor form to send people to hunt a wiki for your details when you could have saved them the time by copying the info right into your post. Just for future reference. You always want to respect peoples time.

Comment: @cksum sure, I wasn't aware it was not a known fact that there was only a single model of that. That said, I still need an answer, I guess I'll have to search it elsewhere, np.

Comment: The [faq] says we don't like hardware shopping questions, but this seems to be perfectly fine. It's asking how things work on a specific model - concrete details as opposed to "Which SSD is best?". The latter type we shut down, but questions like this are not only welcome but encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer:  Other World Computing has extensive tables for their own use of what is compatible with what.  They are also good at answering questions by email.